# NSDateComponents specifying AM/PM?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdatecomponents

I am building up a date using `NSDateComponents` from the following string:

```
"2014-05-17 02:39:00 PM +0000"
```

When I set all the components and return an NSDate I am getting (see method below):

```
"2014-05-17 02:39:00 AM +0000"
```

My question is, is there a way to specify the AM/PM to `NSDateComponent`, or do I just have to add 12 to my hour if the source date is PM?

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromYear:(int)year month:(int)month day:(int)day hour:(int)hour minute:(int)minute {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    [components setYear:year];
    [components setMonth:month];
    [components setDay:day];
    [components setHour:hour];
    [components setMinute:minute];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Comment: Use a 24-hour value, not a 12-hour value.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy thats what I am doing  by adding 12 to the PM values, unfortunately the data from the client uses 12 hour AM/PM notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't seem to specify this.
Apple's own docs on it says this:

> Important:  An NSDateComponents object is meaningless in itself; you
>   need to know what calendar it is interpreted against, and you need to
>   know whether the values are absolute values of the units, or
>   quantities of the units.

Apart from your 12 hours logic, you can alternately use NSDate class [dateWithNaturalLanguageString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a) that uses AM/PM and make use it somehow for your purpose.

Comment: `NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString` is not in iOS - that's only for OS X.

Comment: But, if the format is reasonably well fixed, you can use `NSDateFormatter dateFromString`.  You do need to be sure to set the formatter's locale to @"en_US_POSIX" first, though.